# intent to mail with API above 19

Tags: android, email, android-intent

The function here is to send mail to a user that specified in `taskmail`
the code below was working very well with API 19 but not working with above API 19, can anyone tell me why?

here is the code :

```
if (taskemail.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 &&
     tasktext.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {

     Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     i.setType("message/rfc822");
     i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL ,taskemail.getText().toString());
     i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
     i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
     try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
     } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It gives me this bar above then nothing happen till i close the app

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUorn.png)

Comment: Can you post the logcat (not as a screenshot, please)?

Answer (score 0):

this is the exact code I used on a previous project and it works perfectly fine on API 22

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
                                Uri.parse("mailto:" + Uri.encode(address)));

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, email_subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, email_body);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email via..."));
```

Comment: plz , see the pic above I edit it , it gives me this even when i try your code

Comment: A Screenshot is not really that helpfull so provide the logcat and by the way can you test the code on an actual device because it seems to work on my s5 api 22